# Admitir sólo caracteres alfanuméricos en una cadena

Tags: c#, .net, string

Necesito admitir sólo caracteres alfanuméricos en una cadena y en la cual también pueda tener espacios blancos involucrados (es decir, `"hola 1234"` debe ser válida, pero NO `"hola []"`). Tengo el siguiente código:

```
string campo = string.Empty;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un string no vacio: ");
                campo = Console.ReadLine();

            } while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(campo) && campo.All(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)));

            Console.WriteLine("TEXTO: " + campo);
```

Para realizar esto, utilice la funciones `Char.IsLetterOrDigit` pero no me funciona ya que al poner símbolos,guiones o un espacio vacio `¨{}[]-` me lo admite igual y se me muestra el pantalla y no vuelve a pedir el ingreso de datos.

**PRUEBA:**

**ENTRADA:**

```
{}[]
```

**SALIDA OBTENIDA:**

```
{}[]
```

**SALIDA ESPERADA:**

```
Ingrese un string no vacio:
```

Comment: Esta pregunta es muy parecida a la anterior que hiciste. ¿Te están haciendo los deberes de clase???

Comment: @Peppo No sabía que en clases enseñaban C# jajaja. Cuando encuentres un escuela/universidad que enseñen C# me llamas.  Un saludo

Comment: En la mayoría de las universidades de España, incluyendo UCM, UAM, UPV... Es mas, se da hasta en la Formación Profesional superior. La mayoría de los que estamos por aquí ya hemos pasado por las escuelas y universidades.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu condición en el `WHILE` es incorrecta. Debería ser:

```
while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(campo) || !campo.All(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)))
```

Nota los 2 cambios:

1. OR en vez de AND.
2. NOT en frente de la segunda condición (mientras NO tenga los caracteres esperados... seguimos pidiendo una cadena)

**Edición**

Si deseas permitir espacios también, con tal que la cadena no se componga de espacios solamente, puedes usar la condición siguiente:

```
while (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(campo)
    || !campo.All(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)))
```

Comment: Entiendo, pero ahora no me admite un espacio entre las palabras en la cadena. 


**Ejemplo:**
**ENTRADA:**
Hola Stack
**SALIDA:**
Ingrese un string no vacio:
**SALIDA ESPERADA:**
TEXTO: Hola Stack

.Toma el espacio como caracter invalido porque debe ser solo Letra o Digito.

Comment: ¿No es eso lo que pedistes? Solo caracteres alfanuméricos... No hay nada en tu pregunta que indicara que sí aceptabas espacios.  Obviamente, si quieres aceptar espacios, debes agregar una condición para eso también.

Comment: Pensé que con la correción del while ya admitía espacios blancos la cadena. Ahora re-edito la pregunta así queda archivada.

Comment: @byte96 Lee [Compórtate bien](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) en el centro de ayuda. Y también [ask], para ver cómo hacer mejores preguntas que sea más fácil responder.

Comment: @Peppo Lee [Compórtate bien](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) en el centro de ayuda.